# How do I use vertically stacked divs as pages that each fill browser window?

Tags: html, css, height, liquid-layout

I've seen an effect on a few websites that gives you what are essentially vertical 'pages' which each fill the browser window. Examples:

http://www.bleed.no/

http://www.weworkonsunday.com/

The first is a good deal cleaner and more sophisticated.

I've been puzzling how to achieve this effect. It would be simple enough to do with page anchors etc. if height wasn't an issue, but filling the vertical of the window (as well as the width) is what's throwing me off.

Is there a straightforward method I'm missing? Or is all some complex java tomfoolery?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: What avenues have you explored to achieve this functionality?

Comment: It may indeed use JavaScript (not Java). The best thing to do is get familiar with Firebug or Chrome's developer tools. Use the inspector to see how things are laid out.

Answer (score 0):

This result does require some javascript expertise (in the way thats is implemented in your examples).

There is a jquery library that tries to simplify this process.

http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Even tho there are no really simple way to implement. Among the reasons the effect is very layout dependent and being a "new" way of doing websites... it will take some time until someone tackles the problem.

Here is another example of how to implement parallax in the way you described without teh help of the lib.

HOW-TO: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/
Demo: http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html

you will find plenty other resources if you search for "parallax scrolling".

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific - I meant the various different divs all filling the height of the browser, rather then the parralax effect (though I'm keen to experiment with parralax, your link looks like a great resource)

Comment: Like i said,   It is a complex thing. But your answer is parallax. Check this out...  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/. I'm updating teh answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually I would build a vertical page with stacked divs all with the same class that responds to the height of the window (and also responds when the browser is resized). Untested code using jQuery:

```
<div id="page1" class="page">content</div>
<div id="page2" class="page">content</div>
<div id="page3" class="page">content</div>

<script>

    // set up onResize event handler
    window.onresize = onResizeScreen;

    // run onResize event handler once on load
    $.(function() { onResizeScreen(); });

    // onResize event handler
    function onResizeScreen(event) {
        $(".page").attr("height", screen.height);
    }

    // function to scroll to specific page
    function gotoPage(pageNumber){
        window.scroll(screen.height*pageNumber-1);
    }

</script>

<style>
    .page {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

You sound new to solving these kinds of problems. If you don't know what the above means check up on jQuery and handling JavaScript events.

Comment: Hi ktamlyn, thanks for your response, this is exactly the sort of thing I was thinking of.

I'm pretty new to javascript, I can unpick and understand existing code, but always run into problems when I try to write something myself. Your example makes sense to me, I'll see if I can get it functioning

Comment: Be sure to include jQuery in your attempt to figure my answer out.